# Macro to create table

Tags: tables, expl3

I want to write a macro which creates a table using the arguments as column names. I was able to do the below so far but I would like to make the column names bold. Is there an easy way to do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createTable}{m}
{
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}
\begin{longtable}{*{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}{c}}
    \toprule
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {&} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
\end{longtable}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \createTable{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want an environment, rather than a command that can only produce the headers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylongtable}{m}
 {
  \miglo_longtable_preamble:n { #1 }
 }
 { \end{longtable} }

\seq_new:N \l_miglo_longtable_headers_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \miglo_longtable_preamble:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_miglo_longtable_headers_seq { #1 }
  \begin{longtable}{*{\seq_count:N \l_miglo_longtable_headers_seq }{c}}
    \toprule
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_miglo_longtable_headers_seq \miglo_longtable_headers:nn \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %\endlastfoot
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \miglo_longtable_headers:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 1 } { & } \textbf{#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mylongtable}{a,b,c,d}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
11 & 22 & 33 & 44
\end{mylongtable}

\end{document}
```

With `\seq_map_indexed_function:NN` we can check whether the index is 1 and not insert `&` in that case.

No need to set an `int` variable, because `\seq_count:N` produces an integer denotation that can be used wherever an integer is needed.

[image]